# 2 methods inside with same loop, how can i keep the code dry not repeating it twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question, i have a parent React component and inside this i have 2 methods(functions). With the same loop, where i loop through the state data Object image & title.

I would like to know, how can i simplify this code instead of almost copy pasting the same function with another name.

Code:

```
renderSlides = () => {
    const { data, currentIndex} = this.state

    const slides = data.map((slide, i) => {
      let isActive = (currentIndex === i) ? true : false
      let currentID = i + 1;
      return (
        <SlideContent key={i} image={slide.image} id={currentID} title={slide.title} isActive={isActive} />
      )
    })

    return slides
}

renderPagination = () => {
    const { data, currentIndex } = this.state;

    const paginateCounter = data.map((slide, i) => {
        let isActive = (currentIndex === i) ? true : false;
        let currentID = i + 1;
        return (
            <Pagination key={i} image={slide.image} title={slide.title} id={currentID} isActive={isActive} />
        )
    })

    return paginateCounter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method and pass the component to be rendered as an argument to the function

```
renderComponent = (Component) => {
    const { data, currentIndex } = this.state;

    const componentCounter = data.map((slide, i) => {
        let isActive = (currentIndex === i) ? true : false;
        let currentID = i + 1;
        return (
            <Component key={i} image={slide.image} title={slide.title} id={currentID} isActive={isActive} />
        )
    })

    return componentCounter
}
```

and simply use it like

```
this.renderComponent(SlideContent);
```

or

```
this.renderComponent(Pagination);
```

Comment: Thank you Shubam!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Component constructors are first-class objects, you can pass them around. So you can have a single method to do that work, and pass in the component constructor you want to use.

Roughly (the comment markers highlight the significant changes, I also changed some names in `renderStuff` to make them more generic):

```
renderStuff = (Component) => {
// ------------^^^^^^^^^
    const { data, currentIndex} = this.state

    const entries = data.map((entry, i) => {
      let isActive = (currentIndex === i) ? true : false
      let currentID = i + 1;
      return (
        <Component key={i} image={entry.image} id={currentID} title={entry.title} isActive={isActive} />
// ------^^^^^^^^^
      )
    })

    return entries
}

renderSlides = () => {
    return this.renderStuff(SlideContent);
}

renderPagination = () => {
    return this.renderStuff(Pagination);
}
```

---

Side note: The conditional operator on this is completely unnecessary:

```
let isActive = (currentIndex === i) ? true : false;
```

simply:

```
let isActive = currentIndex === i;
```

sets `isActive` to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this one**

```
renderData = ( TagName ) => {
    const { data, currentIndex} = this.state

    const items = data.map((item, i) => {
      let isActive = (currentIndex === i) ? true : false
      let currentID = i + 1;
      return (
        <TagName key={i} image={item.image} id={currentID} title={item.title} isActive={isActive} />
      )
    })

    return items
}
```